# Undefined reference

Tags: c++

I'm having troubles to compile my C++ project because I get an Undefined reference error.
I have 2 classes:

Vector3.h

```
class Vector3  
{  
public:
float x, y, z;
float v[3];  
Vector3();  
Vector3(float x, float y, float z);  
float mag();  
void normalize();  
void invert();  
void assign(float x, float y, float z);  
Vector3& operator += (const Vector3& in);  
Vector3& operator -= (const Vector3& in);  
Vector3& operator *= (const float& in);  
Vector3& operator /= (const float& in);  
Vector3 operator - ();  
static const Vector3 vZero;  
};
```

Vector3.cpp

```
#include "Vector3.h"

inline void Vector3::assign(float inx, float iny, float inz)  
{  
x = inx;  
y = iny;  
z = inz;  
}  

inline float Vector3::mag()  
{  
return (float)sqrt( (*this) * (*this));   
}  

inline void Vector3::normalize()  
{  
float invMag = 1.f/mag();     
(*this) *=  invMag;  
}
```

Ray.h

```
#include "Vector3.h"  

class Ray  
{  

public:  
Vector3 origin;  
Vector3 direction;  
Vector3 destination;  
float distance;  

Ray();  
Ray( Vector3 o, Vector3 d);  
void setOrigin(float x, float y, float z);  
void setOrigin(const Vector3& v);  
void findDirection(void);  
void setDestination(float x, float y, float z);  
void setDestination(const Vector3& v);  
void findDestination(void);  
void setDirection(const Vector3& v);  
void normalizeDirection(void);  
};
```

Ray.cpp

```
#include "Ray.h"  

void Ray::findDirection(void)  
{  
direction = destination - origin;  
distance = direction.mag();  
direction.normalize();  
}
```

When I compile it using Eclipse IDE I get:

```
/Ray.cpp:39: undefined reference to `Vector3::mag()'  
/Ray.cpp:40: undefined reference to `Vector3::assign(float, float, float)'  
/Ray.cpp:41: undefined reference to `Vector3::normalize()'
```

The header files are included and the auto complete tool works OK, it shows (recognize) the methods: mag, assign and normalize.

I compiled the files using "g++ -c" to create the .o files because eclipse didn't find them. But the error is still there.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Please note that the files Vector3.cpp and Ray.cpp only show the code related to this problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show your compilation commands.

Comment: If eclipse isn't compiling them then it probably isn't going to link them either.  Check your project settings to make sure paths are correct.

Comment: try to include directry the vector3.h inside ray.cpp, is it working?

Answer (score 4):

In Vector3.cpp, remove the `inline` modifier from your functions, or move the function definitions to Vector3.h.

C++ compilers cannot inline functions across modules.  You cannot define an inline function in one module and call it from another.

*Edit*:
From *The C++ Programming Language*, pg 199: "An inline function must be defined - by identical definitions - in every translation unit in which it is used."  pg 200: "To ensure consistency, you should usually place global consts and inlines in header files only."

Comment: Inline functions are not static, the rest is correct, standard requires them to be defined in every compilation unit that uses them.

Comment: C++ compilers *can* inline across compilation units. MSVC calls it Whole Program Optimisation/Link-Time Code Generation. GCC/clang call it Link Time Optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

THe formatting on this questions looks a bit odd, so forgive me if you have already checked these things. Have you:

1. Included vector3.h in the ray.h file? (Or better yeat, forward-declared the vector3 class and included the header file in ray.cpp - thereby minimising compile-time dependancies).
2. Used an include guard around the vector3 class definition?
3. Made sure that you are not using another library in your project that also declared a class called Vector3? This is what namespaces are for - you should use them.

I'd recommend against compiling the object files manually. If your IDE can't find the files then there's something more basic at fault - have you checked your project settings? Specifically, is the folder with vector3.h in the include paths?

Auto-complete tools are often separate from the compiler, so auto-complete working may not be relevant at all.